# Apache error log file is too large whether its cause any error?

Tags: apache, webserver

I am using Apache Server.I have an log file for error. When i tried to open my web console,its not getting opened. So I checked the error log file. I found that file size too large. so I deleted that file and replace an empty file and restarted the Apache server. Now its not getting any error.

My question is, if the error log file size is too large ,it will cause any error, while its trying to write some error log?

Comment: Usually those log files are "rotated", so moved and compressed on a regular base to prevent exactly that. But of course that has to be configured to happen. If not, of indeed your log file grows endlessly, then it might one day hit the limits of your file system and cause problems, indeed. That has nothing to do with apache, but with the file system limitations. Which those are depends on your system. It is not really likely that the error log file will reach that limit. Far more likely is the access log file to cause problems, since that one logs every request your http server processes.

Comment: how can i configure for windows apache server

Comment: I cannot really answer that since I have next to no knowledge about MS-Windows environments (I work based on Linux myself). But in general it can be said that log file rotation as described is not a feature of the server software itself (the apache http server here), but a feature the environment offers (the operating system here). Linux systems bring a package called "logrotate" which offers a very flexible configuration and application of rotation rules. Not sure if such thing exists for MS-Windows environments. I saw a `rotate.exe` somewhere, but that is only half of what is required here.